# Nontotal Points in Cartesian Restriction Category with Zeroes

Tags: category-theory

I am currently working with *Restriction Categories*, a kind of categories of partial maps proposed by Cockett and Lack in [Restriction Categories I](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397500003820). In [Restriction Categories III](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610500) a cartesian structure on Restriction Categories is considered.*

A *restriction terminal* object is an object $1$ such that for each object $X$ there is a unique total morphism $!_X$ and for each morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ it holds that $!_Yf \leq !_X$, ie. $!_X \overline{f} = !_Yf$. A *point* in $X$ is, as usual, a morphism $p:1 \rightarrow X$. A *restriction zero morphism* $0_{XY}:X \rightarrow Y$, which is minimal with respect to the restriction structure.

> I want to know, whether it is true that in a cartesian restriction category with zeroes every point other than $0_{XY}$ needs to be total. If this does not hold in general, I am very keen to learn about minimal requirements making it true.

In the archetypical restriction category $\mathsf{Par}$ of sets and partial functions the restriction terminal is the set $1 = \{*\}$ and we have the homset $\mathsf{Par}(1,1) = \{\emptyset, id\}$. This implies that every nonzero point is a total point. In fact, as a restriction terminal object is a terminal object in the subcategory of total maps, every example I know satisfies this.

My motivation for this problem are the following questions.

1. Is it true that any two distinct total points $p,q:X \rightarrow Y$ are *disjoint* in the sense that there is a complemented restriction idempotent $e$ on $X$ satisfying $ep = p$ and $e^cq = q$?
2. Is it true that any two distinct total points $p,q:X \rightarrow Y$ are *disjoint* in the sense that they don't have a nontrivial meet, ie. $p \cap q = 0_{1X}$?
3. Is it true that given a total point $p:1 \rightarrow X$ and a complemented restriction idempotent $e$ on $X$ the equation $ep = p$ implies $e^cp = 0_{1X}$?.
4. Conversely, is it true that for a total point $p:1 \rightarrow X$ and a complemented restriction idempotent $e$ on $X$ it always holds that either $ep = p$ or $e^cp = p$?

The examples suggest that some of this should hold true, however I could not derive any of it.

Thank you for your time.

*I think my question is quite involved. I admit that this question might not be a part of mainstream category theory and thus don't really expect to get an answer. Nevertheless I think it may be worth giving it a shot.

Comment: I don't know the papers but I would *guess* that there are partially defined points in a restriction category based on a topos whose subobject classifier isn't just $1\sqcup 1$, for instance sheaves on any interesting space, the point being that the terminal object in such a topos has potentially many nontrivial subobjects, and I would guess that a partially defined morphism can have any of them as its domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know any topos theory yet, so I won't be able to construct a counterexample (to my question) myself, but I am ready to believe that one could. I hoped it was true, as it would have fixed many smaller problems...

Comment: OK, the simplest possible example would be in the category $\mathbf{Set}\times \mathbf{Set}$, where you should have points defined on $(*,\emptyset)$ and $(\emptyset,*)$ which are neither zero nor total. If I'm on the right track here then the condition you're asking for is actually very uncommon.

Comment: Incidentally, Kelly does not appear to be an author on this series.

Comment: Again, thank you for giving this example. I should have found this myself. The fail regarding Kelly is even more embarrassing. I recently read a lot of papers from Kelly, Street and Lack and keep confusing them. It is fixed now...